# Где найти ещё 2 гнезда для ОЗУ?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ram, диспетчер-задач

На самой плате вижу только 2 гнезда для ОЗУ, а вот Диспетчер задач пишет, что их 4...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это какая-то приколюха от Винды или реально ещё где-то есть 2 гнезда оперативы?

Comment: А плату надо посмотреть в хрустальном шаре?

Comment: Контроллер памяти может и поддерживает добавочные слоты, но вот производитель имеет полное право их не распаивать на плате.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да говорю же. Там всего 2 гнезда. Просто интересно что это за фигня)

Comment: @gbg, спасибо) Буду знать теперь